# Curl globbing (asterisk expansion) on windows

Tags: windows, shell-script, git-bash, globbing

On windows, in git bash (but in system console too, I think)

Why `curl` ignores all my attempts to disable globbing and expands asterisk?

```
$ GLOBIGNORE="*"; set -f; curl --noproxy "*" "http://www.google.com"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .gitignore
```

Though this works correctly:

```
$ FOO="Abc *"

$ set +f;echo $FOO
Abc .classpath .gitignore .project .settings pom.xml src target

$ set -f;echo $FOO
Abc *
```

Answer (score 0):

curl is not friendly with GLOBIGNORE.

But, may I ask, what are you trying to achieve anyway with your `curl` command?

If you're trying to use the asterisk to get all matching files under a remote directory (such as `curl "http://www.example.com/*"`), then that's not going to work anyway. `curl` cannot list files under a remote directory or make the webserver extend the asterisk.

If the asterisk is meant for `--noproxy` parameter, you can use the alternative approach instead:

```
curl --noproxy `ls *` "http://www.google.com"
```

That will list the files/folders in your current dir after `--noproxy`, with exception for files/folders starting with a dot.

Comment: Hi. That's what I'm trying to avoid. I need to use `--noproxy "*"` but on windows `*` expands so the resulting command is something like `curl --noproxy localfile1 localfile2 localfile3 "http://www.google.com"` so curl tries to connect to "localfile2" address (as you can see in this `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .gitignore`). I'm trying to tell curl to just use noproxy *.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please look at it and tell me if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I can see I didn't make myself clear enough. I want the exact opposite of what you're doing. I want to NOT list the current folder files in place of the asterisk. I want to have an asterisk there. But windows or curl replaces the asterisk with files which is what I want to disable.

Comment: I understand now. But it seems that git bash for Windows does thing differently than the standard bash. Perhaps you want to do it with cygwin's bash?

Comment: Yes, looks like that. Although I'm not entirely sure it's a matter of gitbash, maybe it's a matter of Windows itself.